# Salesforce - find all instances of hyperlink formula

Tags: javascript, salesforce

I've recently become the master of all things Salesforce in my company. Today, Salesforce has announced that it will be eliminating the use of JavaScript in hyperlink formula fields. I have no idea how many instances of this exist in our org - could be zero, could be a thousand. Is there a way to find out?

Comment: According to [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/160923/22382), the Force.com IDE is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Chris:
I think you can run Salesforce Force.com Eclipse. Then:

- Click the search navigation tab.
- Put in a pattern string like "Hyperlink("
- Within the search results, look for all the metadata patterns having something  like:

  hyperlink("javascript:

Force.com Eclipse has the search ability that will pull out all the metadata on your org or at least most of it.

For me much of it seems to exist in the AppExchange packages from vendors.

*Installation See* https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE

*Metadata Search* See https://www.adminhero.com/searching-salesforce-metadata-using-the-force-com-ide/